# Bug in ros::NodeHandle::searchParam()?

Tags: c++, parameter, getparam, server, nodehandle

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

according to my understanding of [searchParam()](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a03010d21f107c80425f346a3508eafb6), the second `if` condition in the following code snippet should never be `true` (probably except for some rare race condition cases which shouldn't happen in my case):

```
  std::string full_param_name, param_name = "a/b";
  if (nh.searchParam(param_name, full_param_name)) {
    if (!nh.getParam(full_param_name, result)) {
      // this should never be reached (but it is reached) ... ?!
    }
  }
```

In particular, see also this [ROS tutorial (wiki)](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server#Searching_for_Parameter_Keys).

However, in my case I have `/a/b` on the parameter server (note the leading `/` -> global) and `param_name` is `a/b` (note the `/` in between: is this allowed?). `searchParam()` returns `true` in that case but `getParam()` returns `false`. The `ros::NodeHandle nh`is initialized with `~` (and, thus, points the node's private namespace). Interesstingly, `full_param_name` is (erroneously) set to `$fully_qualified_namespace_of_my_node/a/b` (which doesn't exist).

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Even if "nested keys" (=  the `/` in between `a` and `b`) are not allowed (are they?), I would assume that `searchParam()` returns `false` ... ?

Thanks!

EDIT: here is a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "test_node");
  std::string full_param_name, param_name = "a/b", result;
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  ros::spinOnce(); // (probably not needed)
  if (nh.searchParam(param_name, full_param_name)) {
    if (!nh.getParam(full_param_name, result)) {
      ROS_FATAL("THIS SHOULD NEVER BE PRINTED ... ?! (%s)", full_param_name.c_str());
    } else {
      ROS_INFO("Okay, parameter found: '%s' = '%s'.", param_name.c_str(), result.c_str());
    }
  } else {
    ROS_INFO("Okay, parameter '%s' not found on the ROS parameter server.", param_name.c_str());
  }
  ros::shutdown(); // (probably not needed)
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> [FATAL] [1507900407.659972647] [/my_namespace/my_node | 7f61d64c4780]: THIS SHOULD NEVER BE PRINTED ... ?! (/my_namespace/my_node/a/b)

Note that `rosparam list | grep "a/b"` returns `/a/b`.

EDIT2: since I am successfully using "nested keys" in my code (at other locations/contexts), I assume that they are allowed.

EDIT3 (@Dirk Thomas): thanks for your assistance / thoughts! I think that I've tracked down the problem correctly now. Your [link](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/38799662b45a42e118762865fac854317b0924a0/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/paramserver.py#L82-L103) was somewhat helpful. For instance, assume the following is stored on the parameter server

```
/a/b: 42
/a/c: 'cannot be found with searchParam using private ns'
/node_namespace/node_name/a/b: 41
```

and I ask for `searchParam(nh_private, "a/b", x)` then `x=/node_namespace/node_name/a/b` (with value 41) and `true` is returned (all fine). However, if I ask for `searchParam(nh_private, "a/c", x)` then `x=/node_namespace/node_name/a/c` and `true` (sic!) is returned but that parameter does not exist (and I don't understand why the docblock states "[...] (yet)"). **IMHO, this behavior of `searchParam()` makes absolutely no sense and I would consider this to be a bug.**

More specifically, my concerns are:

- searchParam() returns true although nothing was found (`/node_namespace/node_name/a/c`).
- searchParam() is said ["to search up the tree for a parameter"](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html#a03010d21f107c80425f346a3508eafb6) but it returns an invalid key *although* there is a (here: global) parameter (`/a/c`) matching the given partial key (`a/c`).

What do you think? ;-)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272703/bug-in-ros::nodehandle::searchparam()?/) by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2017-10-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-13**:
If you feel this is a bug (and you already have a MWE), then I believe it would be better to report this over at [ros/ros_comm/issues](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues).

Edit: ah. I see you already did that: [ros/ros_comm/issues/1187](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/1187).

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-13**:
Yes. ;-) Thanks for referencing the issue, forgot that.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-17**:
Well, the actual behavior seems to match what is written in the docblock (https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/38799662b45a42e118762865fac854317b0924a0/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/paramserver.py#L82-L103). So I assume the behavior is intentionally this way and I don't think this is a bug.

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-18**:
Hm, I disagree since you are referring to the Python docs but I am using roscpp where it is stated that it "returns true if the parameter was found, false otherwise". Clearly, this isn't true. Anyway, I'll write my own version of `searchParam()`.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-18**:
If you think the implementation in both languages is different from each other then please consider to provide a PR which makes them consistent rather than "writing your own".

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-18**:
At least the docs are not consistent, don't you think so?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-18**:
I would interpret it that the Python doc is just more precise where the C++ doc is not clear about the (partial) match.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2018-03-06**:
Just noting that I've recently come across the same problem: `ros::param::search` returns true and gives a `result` path to a parameter that doesn't exist. For example, if I have a param at `/a/b/c/d`, and I call `ros::param::search("a","c/d", res)`, the return value is `true` and `res` is `a/c/d`.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2018-03-06**:
From what I can tell, this isn't an issue with either RosCpp or RosPy client library, but a problem with the payload returned from the XmlRpc call to the parameter server. I haven't been able to find the `"searchParam"` remote API method implementation from the parameter server, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might want to print the value of `full_param_name` after getting it with `searchParam` before calling `getParam`.

The API docs describe the second argument of `searchParam` with:

> [out] result  the found value (if any)

**Update:**

The docblock is kind of misleading. The `result` is actually a parameter key and not a value.

---

When I run your code snippet as-is I get:

- no parameter set: `Okay, parameter 'a/b' not found on the ROS parameter server.`
- after `rosparam set /a/b global_value`: `Okay, parameter found: 'a/b' = 'global_value'.`
- after `rosparam set /test_node/a/b node_value`: `Okay, parameter found: 'a/b' = 'node_value'.`

After calling `rosparam delete /test_node/a/b` I do get `THIS SHOULD NEVER BE PRINTED ... ?! (/test_node/a/b)`.

Maybe you can post the exact steps you are performing when running into the problem.

May this docblock clarifies the behavior of `searchParam` which seems to be the rational for the case above: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/38799662b45a42e118762865fac854317b0924a0/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/paramserver.py#L82-L103

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2017-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-14**:
Thank you very much! That did the trick, sorry for the noise!

Minor follow-up question: it is possible to use `searchParam()` with types other than `std::string`? There just seems to be a string version of that method.

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-16**:
@Dirk Thomas: For some reason, I am unable to reproduce this on my primary dev machine: if I print the value of `full_param_name`, I get `'a/b' = '/a/b'` (the value is 'test_value'). Also, the ROS wiki exactly states that `searchParam()` + `getParam()` is the way to go. Is that an error in the wiki?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-10-16**:
With what other parameter type do you want to call `searchParam()`? `char*` should work too using implicit conversion.

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-17**:
To your last comment: before you edited your answer, you've written that `searchParam()` returns the actual ROS parameter server value in its (last) parameter `result` which obviously isn't the case (see also wiki link in my initial post). My comment just referred to that statement and ...

**Comment by [CodeFinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/26762/codefinder/) on 2017-10-17**:
... doesn't make any sense after your edit/update. With respect to your edit, I've updated my initial post.